# Alert for script filled value

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, kibana-6, elastalert

I am using `Logstash-6.3.0` ,`Elastic search-6.3.0` and  `Kibana-6.3.0` combination. I have some fields in `kibana` which are scripted.

I need to send an alert based on these values. I can send alert for `elastic search` fields using `watcher` plugin for `kibana`.

How do I configure `kibana` to send alert based on scripted field values?

I am using `elastalert`,if there are ways?

Solution using `elastalert` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can query on scripted fields using ElastAlert as [scripted field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html#scripted-fields) values are computed at the query time (in kibana only) and aren't indexed into the Elasticsearch hence cannot be queried on as ElastAlert only queries Elasticsearch directly.

Comment: Are there any other ways to alert based on scripted fields.

Comment: Have you tried this workaround https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/784#issuecomment-299468430